# Does removing html5 media elements also remove memory used by the video/audio?

Tags: javascript, html, memory-management, html5-video, html5-audio

Does removing an html5 media DOM element (video or audio) also free any memory used by the media represented by that element? (assuming no references in code also)

Comment: I understand there are many answers to questions like this one where   code and DOM reference relationships are explained. I am interested particularly in the new html5 elements, since it seems like they are in a partially finished state

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the specification:

**4.8.10.16 Best practices for authors using media elements**

Playing audio and video resources on small devices such as set-top boxes or mobile phones is often constrained by limited hardware resources in the device. For example, a device might only support three simultaneous videos. For this reason, it is a good practice to *release resources held by media elements when they are done playing*, either by being very careful about ***removing all references to the element and allowing it to be garbage collected***, or, even better, by ***removing the element's src attribute and any source element descendants, and invoking the element's load() method***.

Similarly, when the playback rate is not exactly 1.0, hardware, software, or format limitations can cause video frames to be dropped and audio to be choppy or muted.

source: http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-author-view/video.html#media-resource

Answer (score 0):

An object is garbage collected when there is no more reference to it.
If you remove the element from DOM, it is cleared from memory, if there is no variable pointing to it.

In this example, there is variable "img" that still holds the object. So when we remove it from DOM it is not cleared from memory.

```
img.parentNode.removeChild(img);
```

We are able to append it to DOM again.

```
document.body.appendChild(img);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rgH2A/

The above-mentioned concerned MEMORY. Whether to clear files from CACHE or not is up to the browser to decide in any case.

Comment: There appears to be a special case where a video/audio element is not attached to page and has no references, but it is playing anyway. http://jsbin.com/mafigifi/1/edit So you at least have to remove all references AND pause it.

Comment: @brianchirls, agree. It's a memory leak. The element is created, then it floats around DOM without possibility to remove or control it. Writing such code should be avoided.

Comment: I appreciate your answer. In my question, I was being explicit when I said any memory. I am not trying to debate whether cache is the same as memory, but I do mean any memory usage in general that is used by the creation of the tag. Perhaps I could edit the question to clarify this? I am open to suggestions. I believe it is important to know, and hard to find info about, whether a video or audio file is going to be hanging around after its DOM representation is gone.

Comment: Cache is stored on disk, and is normally referred to as storage, not memory. I think I've answered both questions though.