# jQuery .remove() doesn't work with "off-screen" elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to remove an element that is not appended to body.

```
var videoBg;
videoBg = $('<video autoplay>');
videoBg.attr({
    'src': 'http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4',
    'height': 360,
    'width': 640
});

// $('body').append(videoBg);
// NOPE!
```

Then I try to remove it with

```
videoBg.remove();
console.log(videoBg);
```

But it still playing, and console.log also shows that videoBg is a jquery object

EDIT:
Appending the video to the body and deleting it works!
but idk why you can't actually remove a DOM object without having to append it.

Comment: Did you try just to reassign the value of `videoBg`?

Comment: The video is playing without you putting it anywhere? huh?

Comment: @Mathletics yes, with videoBg.get(0).play() works fine ;)
I can hear the audio from it

Comment: _idk why you can't actually remove a DOM object without having to append it._ __Because it isn't in the DOM.__

Comment: @mallendeo That behavior sounds a little unreliable...but either way calling `remove` serves no purpose then. [`...the .remove() method takes elements out of the DOM.`](http://api.jquery.com/remove/) (jQuery docs). If it's not in the DOM, `remove` does nothing. If you want to stop the audio, call `videoBg.get(0).pause()`.

Comment: @nbrooks just a question, if I have tons of videos, and I'm not attaching them to the DOM. Then how can I remove those objects from memory?

Comment: @mallendeo I posted an answer below that addresses that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to dump the source.

```
videoBg.attr('src', '');
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/4t9pzjou/2/

See [this other question about cleaning up multimedia elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22526365).

---

*if I have tons of videos, and I'm not attaching them to the DOM. Then how can I remove those objects from memory?*

Store them all in an object so you can delete them (after clearing the `src`!)

```
var videos = {};
videos['vid1'] = someVideo;
// delete only works on object properties, not variables
delete videos.vid1;
```

Comment: Nice solution. I tried setting the `videoBg[0].src` to blank but couldn't get it working somehow. Thanks for linking that reference to the spec too, that's useful.

Answer (score 1):

jQuerys `$.fn.remove` will only remove elements from the dom and wont unset them. if there is no matching element in the dom, it can't be removed.
see this api: [jQuery/remove](http://api.jquery.com/remove/)

if you try to stop the video use javascript HtmlVideoElement  `.pause`
give your video an id:
`videoBg = $('<video/>', {id: 'myidforthevideo');`
and call

```
videoBg[0].pause();
```

maybe this question will help you also: [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2879227/html5-video-stop-onclose)

Comment: jQuery doesn't have a `pause` method.

Comment: I'm sorry not Jquery meant HtmlVideoElement

Answer (score 1):

One thing to note here is that relying on the video playing even though it's not added to the DOM seems risky. That being said, this trick seems to work for stopping the video when it's not in the DOM. Simply append it to the body, then immediately remove it. Finally, set the variable to `null` so there are no lingering references to the object and it can be garbage-collected.

```js
var $videoBg;
$videoBg = $('<video controls></video>');
$videoBg.attr({
  'src': 'http://vjs.zencdn.net/v/oceans.mp4',
  'height': 540,
  'width': 960
});
$("#play").click(function() {
  $videoBg[0].play();
});
$("#stop").click(function() {
  $videoBg.appendTo('body').remove();
  $videoBg = null;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="play">Play Video</button>
<br />
<button id="stop">Stop Video</button>
```

Comment: That did the trick! :) but I'm not sure if it's completely removed. Try it with your example, play it and stop it, it'll start in the last position

Comment: @mallendeo I updated it just now, try it again. (I missed a line the first time, but I fixed the issue.)

Answer (score 0):

[Here is JSFiddle with working answer](http://jsfiddle.net/p1rka4we/3/)

*Updated JSFiddle to show a way achieve the desired effect, but it's more of a work around. Code is below too. I think the video playing when it is not in the DOM might actually be a browser bug.

```
// Setup video object
var $videoBg;
$videoBg = $('<video controls></video>');
$videoBg.attr({
    'src': 'http://vjs.zencdn.net/v/oceans.mp4',
    'height': 540,
    'width': 960
});

// Add video to body
$('body').append( $videoBg.hide() );

// Play and show
jQuery('button.play').click(function(){
    $videoBg.show()
    $videoBg[0].play();
});

// Remove on click
jQuery('button.remove').click(function(){
    $videoBg.remove();

    // Another way to remove it
   //$('video').remove();    
});
```

As a side note, I always like to give the var a $prefix when it's a jQuery object, just to remind yourself in the future that you are dealing with jQuery objects later. But you don't have to do this by any means.

```
    // Setup video object
    var $videoBg;
    $videoBg = $('<video></video>');
    $videoBg.attr({
        'src': 'assets/videos/' + t.chosenVideo,
        'height': t.videoHeight,
        'width': t.videoWidth
    });
```

From a best practice point of view, I always like to give the var a $prefix when it's a jQuery object, just to remind yourself in the future that you are dealing with jQuery objects later. But you don't have to do this by any means.

Comment: I think it is the same as `$(videoBg).remove();`

Comment: Thanks, but I already tried that way.
console.log(videoBg) returns `[video, selector: "", context: undefined, jquery: "2.1.1", constructor: function, toArray: function…] `

Comment: @DrewBaker he is not adding it to the document!

Comment: Well if I uncomment the add to body line in JSFiddle, I doesn't play the video at all.

Comment: WOW! OK I get it now, that is strange!

Comment: @Drew Double-wrapping the selector is perfectly OK. The `jQuery` method accepts jQuery objects as a parameter.

Comment: @nbrooks, thanks for that. Seems unnecessary, but good to know it works.

Comment: @Drew It's definitely unnecessary--and I agree the conventions you've noted are a better approach.

Answer (score 0):

You can `videoBg = null` to enable the object to the garbage collector. Although you need to append it to the dom in order to play the video.

Example jsbin
http://jsbin.com/wefuyiqate/1/edit?js,console